# Como armazenar a classe PxFixedJoint em um vector

Tags: c++, constraint, physx

Eu estou tentando armazenar a classe `PxFixedJoint` em um `std::vector` com o método `push_back`. Mas o vetor fica sempre vazio, simplesmente não adiciona nada.

A baixo o código.

```
// C++
// Declaração do vector para armazenar os joints
std::vector<physx::PxFixedJoint*> m_lpJoints;

// Criando um joint
physx::PxFixedJoint* joint = physx::PxFixedJointCreate(*physics, m_pPhysicsBody, physx::PxTransform(-offset), _target, physx::PxTransform(offset));

// Armazenando
m_lpJoints.push_back(joint);

// Verificando o tamanho do vetor
std::cout << "size: " << m_lpJoints.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema? Pois aparentemente não tem nada de errado com o código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolvido**

Eu simplesmente armazenei a classe `PxJoint` ao invés de `PxFixedJoint`. Como `PxJoint` é um classe abstrata, eu posso converter para `PxFixedJoint` quando eu quiser.